# Cocoa : How to make a control invisible?

Tags: cocoa, controls

In my application I have some controls like NSButton and NSTextfield I want to turn invisible.
I know I can do it n the Interface Builder but I need to do it in the code.

I still haven't found the right message I need to send to the controls.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
[myView setHidden:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this will also disable the control.  If you want the control to still work, such as for an NSButton, [button setTransparent:YES] is the one to use.